# What is x.fn.x.init[] value shown for $() and $(this) in chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, developer-tools

I have a habbit of debugging JS and jQuery script in some developer tool. I realized Chrome Dev Tools showing x.fn.x.init as a value for $() and $(this). However I dont realize what are these value:

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="jquery-2.0.2.min.js" ></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.widget.js" ></script>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var outstring = "";
        outstring = "" + $() + $(this);
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: when I type $() in chrome console on page with jquery I get empty array [] as a result.  Are you including other libraries that are using the $ symbol?   $(this) inside of document ready function should return the document object wrapped by jquery object.

Comment: added code, those script files are present in the same folder as this html page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually the REAL code behind instantiating `$`

Take a look at the [github source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L76)

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
    // The current version of jQuery being used
    jquery: core_version,

    constructor: jQuery,
    init: function( selector, context, rootjQuery ) {
        var match, elem;
    .....
```

and then at [line 263](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L263)

```
// Give the init function the jQuery prototype for later instantiation
jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

Since you are using the minified version, this gets turned into what you see.