# JQuery NoConflict wrapping not working on this file

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I have a simple javascript file that I need to wrap in JQuery NoConflict but I cannot seem to get it to work. It is a rotating logo wall.

The page is at /t10.html

I have tried implementing the jQuery as variable $j, then anywhere in the script that calls $ I have replace with $j. This works for another script on the site but for some reason it does not work with this script. You can view and download both the CSS and JS files at /t10.html

Tried below, but to no avail.

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict(true);
$j(document).ready(function(){
```

Also tried wrapping the external JS file like the second answer says to do at [How to be a jQuery no.conflict expert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721815/how-to-be-a-jquery-no-conflict-expert). In fact I've tried all of these solutions on that page and still cannot get it to work.

Help!

I cannot put this on the site until I get this wrapped but what I've tried isn't working.

The code that calls the external JS file is below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/brandsbox/brandsbox.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/brandsbox/brandsbox.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){ 

        $.brandsBox.embed('#slider_container', {

            "collection": "/em/customer-wall/collection.xml",
            "cols": 2,
            "rows": 5,
            "scrollingTransitionSpeed": "slow",
            "scrollingDelay": 2000,
            "scrollingMode": "full",
            "startOpacity": 1,
            "hoverOpacity": 1

        });

    });
</script>

<div id="slider_container" style="width: 218px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

---

I tried wrapping it like DoubleU23 suggested but the code did not fire (see same domain name but file /t11.html):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// closure
(function(window, $, undefined){

  // shorthand for $.ready();
  $(function() {
    // put your code here


        $.brandsBox.embed('#slider_container', {

            "collection": "/em/customer-wall/collection.xml",
            "cols": 2,
            "rows": 5,
            "scrollingTransitionSpeed": "slow",
            "scrollingDelay": 2000,
            "scrollingMode": "full",
            "startOpacity": 1,
            "hoverOpacity": 1

        });

    });

})(window, jQuery.noConflict());
</script>
```

Comment: Where is that on your site. Please post the problem code here.

Comment: @Barmar edited original question to answer your question.

Comment: Any update @Barmar? I could really use some help on this issue.

Comment: I don't see any use of `jQuery.noConflict` on t10.html or brandsbox.js. What am I supposed to be looking for, and what are the symptoms of the problem? I go to the site and I see the rotating logo wall.

Comment: Hi Bramar and thanks for checking back. I created a new file called t11.html where I implemented @DoubleU23 solution below. I have also tried every known jquery.noconflict solution known on stackoverflow with no success. t10.html runs great! But when I implement it on my working site (Magento) it conflicts with the prototype libray, hence the noconflict requirement. The goal is to get this script running on its own with noconflict implemented, then I will test that on my main site that has the other libraries that conflict. I can't put it up there now b/c then my add to cart button breaks.thx

Comment: You need to change brandsbox.js to use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: See the part of the jQuery.noConflict expert answer that says what to do if you have an external script that uses `$`.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I did try that before and it failed on the live site. I just did it again and confirmed that replacing $ with jQuery does not break the script, but when I use it on the website it interferes with the Prototype js library and breaks my add to cart button. I ended up putting this file inside of an iframe to isolate the JS and this seems to have worked. I'd give the answer to you but you just commented on it so I am unable to (I think). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @Bramar's and DoubleU23's answers are both technically correct, neither one worked on this script when I had it on the live site. Both solutions work on their own on my test page, meaning the script still fired and did its thing, but neither worked when put on the Magento page.

The issue is with Magento's Prototype JS library interfering with all jQuery scripts on the site. The other jQuery scripts have been fixed by outside developers but I was unable to use them for this project.

The final solution was to create an iframe with the code inside of it and to place it on my Magento template page. This isolated the JS to the iframe and caused on conflicts with Magento items such as the Add To Cart button.

Lesson learned: don't write off iframe's entirely. They may be useful in very limited and unique situations.

Answer (score 0):

```
// closure
(function(window, $, undefined){

  // shorthand for $.ready();
  $(function() {
    // put your code here
  });

})(window, jQuery.noConflict());
```

---

i recommend to always use closures (this wrapper function you're talking about)
you can read more on this topic by the keywords `JavaScript Closures`

Comment: Hi DoubleU23 and thanks for the response. Below is my code wrapped in your function, with my original $(document).ready(function(){ replaced with your $(function() {

Comment: ***See original question as to how I implemented it. It did not work and fire the javascript. I think it has something to do with it calling on an external JS file and that I need to wrap that too somehow.***

Comment: i tried to access jQuery in the console on your site.

`jQuery('.brandsbox_item_image')` returns => `x.fn.x.init[162]`
I dont know which framework this is. but its NOT jQuery.

Seems like you overwrite jQuery (with prototype?) BEFORE you call the noConflict function.

Comment: Hi @DoubleU23 and thanks for the response. I believe it is JQuery as the x.fn.x.init[162] is the "real code" behind JQuery when it is minified, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858153/what-is-x-fn-x-init-value-shown-for-and-this-in-chrome-dev-tools
Also, the script doesn't work when the JQuery.js is missing. While Magento which runs our store on that domain is based on Prototype (the reason why I need JQuery NoConflict), this page is a simple XHTML page with no other libraries loaded except what you see in the code above. Try downloading these files and run it on your server.

Comment: Any update @DoubleU23? I could really use some help on this issue.